# Installation of VCPKG followed by any call to "vcpkg install" results in "Changing the working dir failed"

Tags: visual-studio, vcpkg

When I follow the steps in [the VCPKG documentation page](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) to install on Windows, the noted steps fail on the line `.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`.

**Specifically, these are the steps I follow, exactly according to the instructions at the above link.**

- Run Powershell (not as administrator)
- `cd <parent_directory>`
- `git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git`
- `cd .\vcpkg\`
- `.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`
- `.\vcpkg integrate install`

All above steps (seem to) succeed, until the last (in red, below).

**I see the following output:**

[image: "Changing the working dir failed"]

(Note: the screenshot also shows an additional line at the end - in which I attempted to install a desired package for use in a project - which failed with the same error.)

I looked through the source code of `vcpkg` and found that the offending line of code looks like this (`vcpkg.cpp`):

[image]

Modifying the `vcpkg.cpp` source to display the missing path, rebuilding, and testing shows that the missing directory is:

> `<vcpkg>/installed/...`

...But the `installed` directory does not exist in the `vcpkg` root directory.

Because I am following the basic installation instructions from the `vcpkg` documentation, I'm stumped as to what I am doing wrong, what is wrong in my setup, or what to do about it.

**Can someone please explain why installation of VCPKG followed by any call to "vcpkg install" results in the error `Changing the working dir failed`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I had mistakenly defined the `VCPKG_ROOT` environment variable to a directory that is a subdirectory of the root directory of the `vcpkg` project.**

This is an easy mistake to make, as I describe below.

---

The `vcpkg` executable itself checks for the existence of the `VCPKG_ROOT` environment variable, and if present, uses its value to override the path to the root folder for the `vcpkg` project that is used internally by the running `vcpkg` binary.

I created an environment variable with the same name (`VCPKG_ROOT`) for a different purpose - so that my own downstream application could be provided the path to the `include` files for a library *installed* by `vcpkg`.  It makes sense that I would choose the name `VCPKG_ROOT`, because in fact `vcpkg`, by default, installs libraries into a subdirectory of its own root directory.

Specifically:

- If the root directory of the 'vcpkg' project is `<vcpkg>`...
- ...then by default the `vcpkg` executable installs libraries such that the include paths for the libraries that are installed are placed in `<vcpkg>\installed\...\include\`

(And other library files, such as binaries, are also placed in directories nested within `<vcpkg>`.)

The problem was that I defined `VCPKG_ROOT` to be the second bullet, not the first. So it's an easy mistake to make, given that the choice of name "`VCPKG_ROOT`" kind of makes sense in both scenarios!

I just suggested an improved error message via a [pull request to the `vcpkg` project](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/7229) - if accepted, this might save some other poor soul the stress and lost time of tracking down this glitch.